# Pass multiple types as a unified type?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I currently have two "*worker services*" that invoke an action specified by the caller, while passing a "*context*" to the action:

```
public interface ISampleContext { ... }
internal sealed class SampleContext : ISampleContext { ... }
public static class SampleWorker {
    public static void Run(Action<ISampleContext> action) =>
    action(new SampleContext());
}
```

Pretty straight forward.

---

Now, I mentioned I have two of these. Let's call them `WorkerA` and `WorkerB` for simplicity, and assume they're both set up the way defined above (keeping in mind they both have dedicated "*contexts*"). Both of them provide different services, and are often used together:

```
WorkerA.Run((contextA) => {
    WorkerB.Run((contextB) => {
        DoSomething();
    });
});
```

Now I have two issues with this:

- I need to add a `WorkerC` to this.
- This is used ***a lot***.

---

I'm trying to create a unified "*worker service*", in an effort to reduce the nested calls as I introduce more "*worker services*". The concept is that the call would include type arguments to the required "*worker services*", like so:

```
GlobalService.Run<WorkerA, WorkerB>((context) => {
    DoSomething();
});
```

That part is easy to accomplish. However, a sharp mind will notice an issue with that setup.

---

### XY Clarifications

It was pointed out in a comment that this question is a perfect example of an XY problem, so I wanted to take the time to break down what I'm currently doing with these "*worker services*". The three services I will have as of this afternoon are for:

- Analytics
- Exception Logging
- A Common Iterator

The analytics worker service simply records the start and end times of the execution of actions so that I can see where I have delays in my code.

The exception logging worker service catches unhandled exceptions, logs as much information as possible, and re-throws them. This allows me to have insight into where my code has issues that are swallowed upstream for any reason, so that I can repair the code that's broken, and, repair the code that's swallowing the exception in the first place.

The common iterator is for re-attempting calls to SQL or APIs. It's simply a `for` loop that executes with a delay on failure, until told to break out, or the action returns `true`, or the maximum number of allowed attempts has been reached.

With this knowledge, you can see how I may have some areas that can use all three services at one time, while other areas may only use one or two.

---

How do you access the properties and methods from each individual "*context*", without sending each one through individually?

For example:

```
public interface IContextA { void PostA(); }
public interface IContextB { void PostB(); }
public interface IContextC { void PostC(); }
...
GlobalService.Run<WorkerA, WorkerB>((context) => {
    context.PostA();
    context.PostB();
    context.PostC(); // This is not valid as WorkerC was not specified.
});
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in a way that is scalable and easy to maintain, without using `dynamic` or similar?

<sub>*By scalable and easy to maintain, I mean that I shouldn't have to create multiple new interfaces and classes when introducing new "*worker services*".*</sub>

Comment: If my question is not useful, or could be improved, please tell me how I can improve it and I will do so. I'm fully aware that the answer may just be that it's not possible.

Comment: If creating a containing type is not an option, then how about working with a list of contexts to pass to the lambda? You could then resolve any one you want using type.

Comment: Also, when you say it's used a lot, you mean throughout your app's lifecycle? As in, running these workers is not something you do once when the app starts up?

Comment: @Crono it's not out of the question, though does introduce the need for the caller to determine how to get the context they desire, which seems inefficient, as you mentioned lol  I may have no other option but to create a containing type instead.

Comment: IMO this question is a great example of an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Crono that is correct, these are called throughout the application's lifecycle. Currently one logs and re-throws unhandled exceptions, another records execution times for the specified actions, and I'm introducing one for performing some very, very common iteration logic for re-attempting execution of calls to SQL and APIs.

Comment: @chancea I do that a lot. 

Comment: You can't call `PostA()`, `PostB()`, `PostC()` from `context` unless `context` implements all of those interfaces. Does it?

Comment: @Kit I'm thinking that there is no solution that makes that possible, and that's the problem I had mentally. I think the best solution in this case is to pass each context individually, as needed. The problem there is you end up with chains of context arguments: `.Run((contextA, contextB, contextC, ..., contextZ) => { ... });` while not probable, it is possible and can be rather verbose IMO.

Comment: This is not possible because of the multiple contexts. Read up on Chain of Responsibility design pattern.. If there is one common context that is able to resolve the others, then just maybe there may be a path there.

Comment: @Nkosi this screams chain of responsibility after reading a few articles. Thank you!

Comment: @Tacoタコス glad to help. Happy coding!!!

Comment: I don’t know if I’m understanding the problem, but can’t you use a list/array of actions? Or a defined delegate and add all the methods of the objects that you need and run it in a for loop?

Comment: You seem to apply cross cutting concerns by nesting static functions. Instead of using this more functional approach, take a look at the Decorator design pattern; a more OOP approach.